# мало места на диске

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня Ubuntu 12.04LTS. Постоянно появляется сообщение "мало места на диске".

Я не знаю и не понимаю, как удалить. Я бы очень хотел научиться сам, но не могу понять.

Я хотел установить Ubuntu 14.04LTS, но у меня не получается из-за "мало места на диске". Подскажите, как это сделать.

Прилагаю изображение из терминала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Причем тут ваши проблемы со слухом?

Comment: Возьмите диск бОльшего размера. или добавьте второй. И за вас никто не может принять решение какие файлы нужны в вашей системе а какие нет. Что у вас в /home так много места занимает, может там что нибудь стоит удалить ? Вообще 10-15Гб на современные linux системы маловато, если вы не гуру и не можете по каждому компоненту ОС решить нужен он вам или нет

Comment: Добрый день. Скажите о каком обьёме памяти идёт речь?
Скалько на жёстком диске у вас есть?
Какой обьём памяти оперативки?
На скриншоте у вас Ubuntu м окружением Unity. Если компьютер не новый, то может стоит попробывать ubuntu с окружением LXDe?
Выполните код в терминале и пришлите информацию
sudo fdisk -l

Comment: Немного не по теме. Есть на клавиатуре клавиша "Print Screen". Существует с незапамятных времён. Если её нажать один раз, то она сделает то же, что и ты сделал мобильником\фотоаппаратом, только быстрее и качественее.

Comment: Теперь по теме: если операционка пишет, что "недостаточно места на диске", это значит, что недостаточно места на диске (внезапно!). Дополни вопрос выводом комманд "df -h" и "sudo fdisk -l".

Answer (score 1):

> Постоянно появляются"мало места на диске"

скорее всего, речь о недостатке свободного места в файловой системе. можете поудалять «лишние» пакеты и «лишние» файлы в своём домашнем каталоге (`/home/имя-пользователя`).

> Я хотел установить Ubuntu 14.04LTS, но у меня не получается из-за"мало места на диске".

а тут, скорее всего, речь об отстутствии неразмеченного пространства на диске.

вы можете (прямо в программе установки) удалить, например, те разделы, что используются в настоящий момент установленной *ubuntu 12.04*. их должно быть как минимум два — корневой раздел (со всеми этими файлами и каталогами, что вы видите на прикреплённой вами фотографии) и [раздел подкачки (*swap*)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86#Unix) и продолжить установку — программа установки сама найдёт освободившееся место.

**внимание!** — при этом все ваши сохранённые файлы/каталоги «исчезнут», и те, что вам действительно нужны, имеет смысл сохранить на какой-нибудь другой носитель.